# Django-Bootstrap3 issues with inline form layout

Tags: django, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3, inline

Using the following code to render a form:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6  col-lg-offset-3">
    <form action="{% url 'chartboard:chart_url' %}" method="post" class="form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% bootstrap_form form layout='inline' %}
        {% buttons %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            {% bootstrap_icon "star" %} Submit
        </button>
        {% endbuttons %}
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the output:

[image]

And here it is when removing `layout='inline'`

Datepicking is done by adding a custom class upon form creation with form widgets and using a jquery datepicker (if that is of any relevance at all)

[image]

1. Why are field labels being hidden in the first case?
2. Why isn't the entire form displayed in a single line when opting for `inline` display?

Working with python 3.4 and the following venv:

```
Django==1.8.11
django-bootstrap3==7.0.1
flake8==2.5.4
mccabe==0.4.0
numexpr==2.5
numpy==1.10.4
pep8==1.7.0
pyflakes==1.0.0
requests==2.9.1
tables==3.2.2
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the class of your `<form>` element to `class="form-inline"` and it should work. It doesn't seem to appear in the docs but check the [example inline form on GitHub](https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3/blob/develop/demo/demo/templates/demo/form_inline.html).